# How do I remove parent opacity in CSS?

Tags: css

In my CSS I have the following:

```
.Thing {
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
    opacity:0.4;
    -moz-opacity:0.4;
}

.Thing button {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity:1;
    -moz-opacity:1.0;
}
```

However, the button is still .4 opacity. I then try `opacity: 2` and such and it looks like I can give it less opacity but not more. Is there a way I can remove it or do I have to write multiple rules to get everything but the button?

I am testing with Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: You cannot remove parent opacity, if you draw anything on a 20% opaque surface the most you will ever get is 20% opaque.

Comment: @Serdalis I was very much hoping that wasnt the case :(

Comment: Best CSS only way around this is to use rgba color on the element you want some transparency on. Support isn't universal for rgba yet is the main caveat to keep in mind.

Comment: @kinakuta: rgba doesnt help as the transparency of a child textarea will blend the parent div background color THEN the site background instead of just bleding the site background image

Comment: I'm trying to picture what you mean but I don't think I'm quite getting it. Do you have a jsfiddle or something to demonstrate what you mean?

Answer (score 9):

use `rgba` with a `rgb` fallback.

```
background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5); /*ie6 will ignore this*/
```

`rgba` will only apply opacity to the target element.

What i've recently been doing is using the [rgbapng](http://aaronrussell.co.uk/legacy/cross-browser-rgba-support/) [sass](http://sass-lang.com/)/[compass](http://compass-style.org/) plugin which generates a png image to use as a fallback for browsers without rgba support.

Note: you'll still need to use an ie6 png [fix](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/) for this to work.

Comment: My site actually doesnt support IE and everything on it fails miserably. So i wont attempt IE6 support =). This did not work as the white textarea isnt transparent and when i do .4 or .5 it chains with the background color of .Thing THEN the background of the site. Which looks horrible :(. +1

Comment: i didn't understand that. Can you post a js fiddle or some code?

Comment: Well i mean using this does... This textarea which is white is instead of being .4 white and .6 the background image the site uses. It is instead .4 white then .6 of the parent background color (which is black) THEN the background image. The black from the parent makes it look bad.

Answer (score 1):

Not a fix for the `opacity` issue but a possible workaround.

How about removing the `button` from the normal document flow and then placing back inside the `.Thing`

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/CqgkM/